# itunesconnect login error - Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I can't login to my itunesconnect account. My email is validated, i can login to provisioning portal, to appleid.apple.com but not to itunes connect. It returns an error: **Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect.** How to solve this problem? Or maybe i need to send email to support?

I had an access, troubles began when i tried to login from another place

Answer (score 0):

Send and email to support this is not a common issue. If you are part of the developer program you should have access to iTunes connect by default, unless they are awaiting some documentation from your part.